# How to Bind IsChecked Property of Menu item

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

Here My code to bind `IsChecked` property of menu.

```
<MenuItem Header="_View">
                <MenuItem  IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=TermMenu, Path=IsChecked}" Header="Term" />
                <MenuItem  IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="True" Header="Key"  />
                <MenuItem  IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="True" Header="Hand"  />
                <MenuItem  IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="True" Header="Rule"  />
            </MenuItem>
```

Here is the context menu

```
<ContextMenu x:Key="DataGridColumnHeaderContextMenu" >
                    <MenuItem x:Name="TermMenu" IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="True" Header="Key Term"  />
                    <MenuItem x:Name="Key" IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="True" Header="Key Term Description"  />
                    <MenuItem x:Name="ShortHand" IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="True" Header="Hand"  />
                    <MenuItem x:Name="Rule" IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="True" Header="Rule"  />

                </ContextMenu>
```

Now I want when the context menu item is check the main menu View will be checked automatically. But my code is not working. Please explain me why.

Comment: just entered your code in a sample app. the binding works as expected. i added the context menu directly. i didn't use it as a resource

Comment: It stops working though if you use it as a resource. Maybe he should bind both checkboxes to the viewmodel instead.

Comment: If I use style trigger, the problem will solve or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

x:Name does not work in resources. the element with the specified name in ElementPath does not exist. this is why the binding doesn't work. you can't access TermMenu from the code behind either. You should bind both to a view-model as @wilford sugested.